# SQL display record that occurs after the most recent of a specific date type in a field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a set of records about a van (serialnumber, job number, job type, and current mileage).

```
select serial_number, call_ref, call_type_description, callm_data19
from calls
left join equipment on link_to_equipment=equipment_code
inner join lu_call_types on call_type=call_type_code
left join call_more on call_ref=callm_link_to_call
where serial_number = 'SH12ZLN'
order by call_ref desc
```

I want to be to able to just show the next "van inspection" record that occurs after the most recent "van service" record.

here is a snapshot of the data

```
SH12ZLN 3023152 Van Inspection  83980
SH12ZLN 3019319 Van Inspection  83046
SH12ZLN 3016999 Van Servicing   NULL
SH12ZLN 3016346 Van Inspection  81818
SH12ZLN 3012977 Van Inspection  80742
SH12ZLN 3010435 Van Inspection  79909
SH12ZLN 3008528 Van Repairs NULL
SH12ZLN 3006880 Van Inspection  78577
SH12ZLN 3001942 Van Inspection  76974
SH12ZLN 2998209 Van Inspection  75976
SH12ZLN 2994475 Van Inspection  75285
SH12ZLN 2991756 Van Repairs NULL
SH12ZLN 2989642 Van Inspection  74408
SH12ZLN 2985795 Van Inspection  73642
SH12ZLN 2981952 Van Inspection  72838
SH12ZLN 2978257 Van Inspection  72011
SH12ZLN 2975667 Van Inspection  70692
SH12ZLN 2972244 Van Inspection  69732
SH12ZLN 2969157 Van Inspection  68821
SH12ZLN 2959335 Van Inspection  67891
SH12ZLN 2956295 Van Inspection  66994
SH12ZLN 2948516 Van Inspection  66481
SH12ZLN 2946213 Van Inspection  65778
SH12ZLN 2939497 Van Inspection  64408
SH12ZLN 2937538 Van Inspection  63765
SH12ZLN 2934421 Van Inspection  62937
SH12ZLN 2932707 Van Inspection  61645
SH12ZLN 2930711 Van Inspection  60713
SH12ZLN 2930023 Van Inspection  59683
SH12ZLN 2924989 Van Inspection  58372
SH12ZLN 2924830 Van Repairs NULL
SH12ZLN 2922412 Van Inspection  57474
SH12ZLN 2919005 Van Servicing   NULL
SH12ZLN 2918376 Van Repairs NULL
```

to clarify - i want it to only produce the following record

```
SH12ZLN 3019319 Van Inspection  83046
```

Comment: Please learn to format your questions after 13 posts

Comment: i was just in the process of editing to correct for format when you did it.

Comment: Please do it before posting in the future. You can see how it looks in the preview below the editor.

Comment: yes i know, it was a simple mistake that i was in the process of fixing.

Comment: Please consider posting queries you have tried before posting message, not 5 mins after.

Comment: i see John Woo has marked this as duplicate, but hasn't offered a link to what it is a duplicate of.

i found similar questions, but not one that posed the exact same set of criteria that i am looking for. maybe my search parameters weren't precise enough.

Comment: ok tvelykyy, we all strive to be as perfect as yourself.
as i said, i made an error during posting and i corrected it.
does this community strive on jumping on people for making minor mistakes which are then corrected, or is it about helping people who have questions?

Comment: @john woo - the suggested duplicate you link does not appear to be the same question i am asking

Comment: @chenks, what 'most recent' means? What's the criteria?

Comment: i have edited the question to remove any ambiguity (i hope).
also at the end of the question i have added the only record that i would want it give as a result.

basically it should display only 1 record, and that record should be the next "van inspection" job that occurs after the most recent "van service" job.

Comment: @chenks, to confirm: the higher the job_number - the later event (inspection or servicing)?

Comment: yes, the higher the number the more recent it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After problem clarification I've edited my answer.
To solve this you should find the highest job_number of 'Van Servicing' type that would mean the recent one. You could it with subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(job_number) FROM tbl WHERE id = 'SH12ZLN' AND type = 'Van Servicing'
```

After you you have most recent servicing job_number just filter rows with job_number higher than recently found and select row with the lowest job_number.

Final query could look like following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbl WHERE 
job_number > (SELECT MAX(job_number) FROM tbl WHERE id = 'SH12ZLN' 
    AND type = 'Van Servicing')
AND type = 'Van Inspection'
ORDER BY job_number ASC
```

Check out sqlfiddle to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64dfc/2

P.S. As I can from initial problem, your sample data is received from query itself. Your query could enhanced to return desired, but I need schema for all tables.

Comment: this will only return one record.

Comment: this seems to work as expected (although i had to make one small change)

Comment: Curious to know that kind of change.

Comment: i had to add "id = 'SH12ZLN'" to the out select also.

Comment: i have a follow up question to this
how would i modify to this to display the relevant result for a fleet of vans... ie all vans where make='fiat' and model='fiorino'